# Workflow actions script can't set field value

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I was tasked to set a workflow action script that sets a field value upon CSV Import but I was given an error of "Cannot call method setValue of undefined". What are the common symptoms for this and how should I deal with it? Here is my code

```
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType WorkflowActionScript
 * @NModuleScope public
 */
define(['N/record'], function (r) {
 r.Record.setValue({
 type: r.Type.PURCHASEORDER,
 fieldId: 'memo',
 value: 'CSV Field script',
 ignoreFieldChange: true,
 });
return{
  onCreate: 
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workflow scripts have a single entry point of `onAction`. Also, I don't understand why you would use a workflow script to set a field value when that is already an available workflow action option.

If for some crazy reason you have to do this, I would use your workflow action to pull the ID of the record and then pass that value to a separate function. The function would be something like:

```
function setMemo(recordId){
     record.submitFields({
          type: record.Type.SALES_ORDER,
         id: recordId,
          values: {
               'memo': 'CSV Field Script'
               }
          })
      }
```

Comment: I don't know even why I am tasked to do this. I have already passed a working workflow but my boss wants me to do it via action script. It's been a while since he gave me weird tasks.

Comment: @AeolCross what you're asked to do isn't actually possible. If you reference the SS2.0 API guide, you'll see that WorkflowAction script context allows for both oldRecord and newRecord, but specifies that you cannot save.

I'll add some options to actually make this happen, but it wouldn't be worth your time really.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It helped me now to progress and yeah I better say it before I even do something more than this.